# How to set consistency level for all queries using Cassandra Java Driver?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

On an earlier version I would do something like this:

```
QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE)
cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .withQueryOptions(queryOptions)
        ...
        .build();
```

I can't find a way to do this with DataStax Java Driver 4.2

The closest I could find is

`boundStatement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE);`

but I would like to set the level for all queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java driver 4.x, configuration is done other way - you either specify configuration options in `application.conf` file (preferred method), or specify it programmatically via `DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder` (mostly useful for tools builders).  See [driver documentation for details](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/configuration/).

For your case, you need to specify values for following configuration parameters (see [configuration reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/configuration/reference/) for details, also in [source code](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/resources/reference.conf)):

- `datastax-java-driver.basic.request.consistency` for "normal" requests;
- `datastax-java-driver.basic.request.serial-consistency` for lightweight transactions;

P.S. It's better to upgrade to latest version - 4.6.0 was released yesterday...